# Magento: What is the url to the confirmation page?

Tags: magento

I've been added some affiliate tracking code to my website.  In order for the tracking to work I need to supply the affiliate company with the confirmation paage url.

I'm using Magento, I'm unsure of the version but its not been updated in a few years.  I need to know what the url of the order confirmation page/thank you page is.  Can anyone help me with this?

I'm thinking its something like `www.mysite.com/index.php/success`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is your success url :  www.mysite.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/success/

Answer (score 3):

You can finde magento version in the bottom in admin.

success.phtml url:
`app/design/frontend/<yourPackage>/<yourTheme>/template/checkout/success.phtml`

If success.phtml file is not there, then find it in: 
`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/ path and copy success.phtml` file to `app/design/frontend/yourPackage/yourTheme/template/checkout/` . 
Edit the file here.

To check your code, the easiest for you would be just to create a new test order. Once created you will be redirected to success page.

Answer (score 3):

The order Success URL of your website would be **www.mysite.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/success** (It is resulted from Success action of Onepage Controller in Checkout Module)

If you have enabled the setting **Use Web Server Rewrites** (under Search Engine optimization) from System -> Configuration -> Web then you can simply use **www.mysite.com/checkout/onepage/success** as your order confirmation URL.